# problem loading .properties file in java

Tags: java

I am having problem while loading .properties file.
The following works:

```
private static Properties props = new Properties();
 ................
 .......................
 configurationProps.load(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));
```

But this;

```
private static Properties props = new Properties();
 ................
 .......................
 configurationProps.load(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\someFilder\\test.properties"));
```

gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:267)
 at Test.init(Test.java:24)
 at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

I am wondering why its not taking full path.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
configurationProps.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\..."));
```

Using `getResourceAsStream` delegates to the ClassLoader and thus typically only works relative to the classpath.  The rules for where it searches are given in the [Javadoc for `getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Answer (score -2):

```
private static Properties props = new Properties();
 ................
 .......................
 configurationProps.load(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../C:\\someFilder\\test.properties"));
```